# Facebook Login integration using PHP SDK 4.0 - HTTP_REFERER missing on redirect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I was trying to integrate Facebook Login using **PHP SDK 4.0**. Everything is going good except `HTTP_REFERER` is missing in the page redirected by Facebook after successfull login (User authorizes the app and grants requested permission.)

Login page:

```
<?php
...
$loginHelper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('localhost/login/facebook/verify.php');
$loginURL = $loginHelper->getLoginUrl();
header("Location: $loginURL");
...
?>
```

`verify.php` page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com') !== false) {
        // Redirected from Facebook
       ...
    }
}
?>
```

The **php.net** documentation states :

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by    the user agent. Not all user agents
>   will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as
>   a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

So, is it really Facebook not setting this particular header or I'm doing it wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your web browser that should set the `HTTP_REFERER` header not Facebook itself. When your site is being linked or redirected from a `HTTPS` site, the browser will not set a referrer.

Comment: Yeah. Facebook OAuth uses secured URL. So, no chance of knowing the referer when the URL is HTTPS?

Comment: any chance of knowing the URL?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be counted as a security bug in browsers if you could. And why would you need it?

Comment: I wanted to check if it is facebook redirecting. Nevermind, I will have to improvise now. And thanks.